# CsQuery or Jint? Javascript data manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jint, csquery

I'm writing a web crawler for statistic purposes.
The website dynamically updates through javascript.
I managed to parse the HTML file and copy all script values into an array.
How do i re-execute these scripts locally or on-the-fly in order to get the return values?
CsQuery, Jint or other method?

Comment: Depending on your goals (i.e. implement full .Net-only browser vs. scraping dynamic pages) using PhantomJS or embedded browser (i.e. built in [WebBrowserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) or similar controls on the other engines) may be easier.

Answer (score 2):

CsQuery is a complete DOM manipulation library for `.NET`. 
While it is awesome, it can not "re-execute" scripts. That would require an actual JavaScript interpreter (like Jint).

If you need to actually simulate a browser for getting AJAX responses and that sort of stuff, I've personally had a lot of success with Selenium.